# What are the cluster points of this filter?

Tags: general-topology, filters

Let X be a topological space, $A\subset X$ and $\mathcal{F}=\{F\subset X|A\subset  F\}$. Then $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter on X. I would like to know what are the cluster points of this filter.

I am preparing for an exam and I need help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: The cluster points of any filter $\mathscr{F}$ on a space $X$ are the points of the set $\bigcap_{F\in\mathscr{F}}\operatorname{cl}F$. What is $\bigcap_{F\in\mathscr{F}}\operatorname{cl}F$ for your particular filter?

Comment: I imagined it was Cl_A, but what does this really mean? I still don't know, is this A fixed, if it is fixed then the points inside the closure of A are the cluster points. Am I way off?

Comment: @Klara: No, you’re exactly right: $A$ is a fixed set, and the cluster points of $\mathscr{F}$ are precisely the points of $\operatorname{cl}A$.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian.

Comment: @Klara: You’re very welcome.